# Identity Server + resource owner credentials + authenticator

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I'm working on setting up a new SSO application. I would like to use ASP.NET Identity as a database to store the users data. I have a ReactJs application hosted on Node.JS and a .Net Web Api2 application. I want to protect thsi Web Api 2 using Identity Server with users from its database. In further development I'm going to create a mobile application. 
I'm able to create an asp.net identity database with some users and use Resource Owner credentials, but I have couple of questions if anyone could help:

1. Why is Resource Owner Credentials not recommended? My current workflow is to hit the api with client&user&password and obtain a token which I store in web layer and  use in Web Api requests. Web Api validates the tokens and identify the user. I read on IS page that's not recommended then what's the recommended scenario to authenticate the user?
2. How can I create an authenticator for mobile? Should I create my own certificate issue, store it in database as a thumbprint and use access token for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. In short, Resource Owner requires the credentials to be passed through the application itself, also RO doesn't give you SSO. Here's a longer [answer](http://lutando.net/2016/10/the-resource-owner-password-grant-is-an-anti-pattern-in-the-face-of-oauth-openidconnect/). The recommended scenario is to use hybrid flow with PKCE enabled.
2. Look up [TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238). I believe it is implemented in [AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=totp&type=) with some examples.

Comment: The long answer for 1) is dead. Can you update your answer or provide a working link?

Comment: @stt106
 
1) The RFCs recommendations [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-10.7) 


2) [Here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) is a good blog post on it with more details


Apologies for that URL in this post (it is my blog) im currently moving host providers, should be back soon.

Comment: Thanks for that. Please let me know when your blog is back online. I read Scott's post on why ROPC grant is bad but honestly I still don't fully understand the reasoning. Other flows like implicit allow users to enter username and password; and that's ok but not with ROPC flow? Maybe I am missing something fundamentally at the protocol level; will be good to read your blog on this.

Comment: With Implicit flow, The username and passwords are entered through the identity provider itself. Conversely with RO flow, the username and passwords are entered through the application which are then sent to the IDP. This flow can only work if you assume trust with the application sending the credentials.

Also have a read of N. Sakimuras answer to Question 3 on this page  - https://nat.sakimura.org/2017/11/09/1370/